# How to calculate average of specific rows in a column in R

Tags: r, average

My data frame (stock market info) has around 100 groups (stocks) and each group (stock) has 25 observations (rows - 1/day). It looks something like this.

```
Stock   Day   Price   Volume

A       1     x       y 
A       2     a       b
.
.
A       25    c       d
B       1     p       q 
B       2     r       s
.
.
B       25    t       u
.
.
.
XX       1     e       f
XX       2     g       h
.
.
XX       25    i       j
```

Now I want to calculate average price and volume for the last 3 days (Day 1-3), 5 days (Day 1-5) and for 20 days from the back (Day 5 - 25) for each group(stock).

Result will look like this

```
Stock Pr/3D/Avg Pr/5D/Avg Pr/20D/Avg Vo/3D/Avg Vo/5D/Avg Vo/20D/Avg

A      a1         b1         c1        d1         e1        f1
B      g1         h1         i1        j1         k1        l1
.
.
.
XX     m1         n1          o1       p1         q1        r1
```

How can I do this?

I tried head, but it is taking the first rows of only the first group.
I feel there is an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, here is one way -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Stock) %>%
  summarise(across(c(Price,Volume), 
            list(avg_3D = ~mean(.[match(1:3, Day)], na.rm = TRUE), 
                 avg_5D = ~mean(.[match(1:5, Day)], na.rm = TRUE), 
                 avg_20D = ~mean(.[match(5:25, Day)], na.rm = TRUE))))

#  Stock Price_avg_3D Price_avg_5D Price_avg_20D Volume_avg_3D Volume_avg_5D Volume_avg_20D
#  <chr>        <dbl>        <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>          <dbl>
#1 A            0.256        0.194       -0.0796        0.0606        0.265         -0.0616
#2 B           -0.232       -0.116        0.209        -0.160        -0.0875         0.351
```

I have used `match` instead of `head` and `tail` because if a particular day is not present in the data it will return `NA` for it (which will be removed with `na.rm = TRUE`) but `head` and `tail` would return an incorrect value.

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a [reproducible format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) -

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Stock = rep(c('A', 'B'), each  =25), 
                 Day = 1:25, 
                 Price = rnorm(50), 
                 Volume = rnorm(50))
```